# "unknown error: cannot read property 'scrollleft' of null" in Chrome using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

In Chrome when I am clicking button, I am getting "unknown error:

```
cannot read property 'scrollleft' of null
```

Their is 1 Input field in that page I am able to enter value in that only Button click is not working.
This Click is working fine in Firefox. issue only in Chrome

```
IWebElement element = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(locator));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
element.Click();
```

Note:
There is no frames in this page, no scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke `Click()` once the element is returned through *WebDriverWait* as follows:

```
IWebElement element = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(locator));
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element)).Click();
```